# How to set param of store.proxy

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
var gridStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Person',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: '?operant=2',
            create: '?operant=3',
            update: '?operant=4',
            destroy: '?operant=5'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message',
            extraParams: {
                user_id: "some text",
                another_param: "more text"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried use baseParams 、 params ,I use fiddler to look ,the extjs no send this, how to do?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it shows some workaround for your problem: http://www.learnsomethings.com/2011/05/17/where-did-setextraparam-aka-setbaseparam-go-in-extjs-4-%E2%80%93-one-workaround/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for `extraParams`, which is a config under the `proxy`. Example:

```
proxy: {
    url: "some_page.jsp",
    extraParams: {
        user_id: "some text",
        another_param: "more text",
        // add as many as you need
    }
}
```

These extra parameters will be sent in your requests. There are also default params set by the Ajax proxy class: `pageParam, sortParam, groupParam, filterParam, limitParam`. Set these to `undefined` to remove them from the request.